# What to do about this off-topic question that's too old to migrate (but has a useful answer)?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, migration

I came across this question today:

[If I know the total amount of people will arrive to an event within 1 hour, what distribution should I use to simulate the arrival time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003589/if-i-know-the-total-amount-of-people-will-arrive-to-an-event-within-1-hour-what)

It's clearly off-topic for SO and although it may make sense on another site, it's too old to migrate.

There is one useful answer.

What should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vote to close it since it *is* off-topic.  There's not much in the way of lasting value for the main audience of Stack Overflow, since the question is rooted more in math than programming.

If they want a math-oriented answer to this problem, there's always [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Looks more like Stats than Math to me. But I wouldn't migrate something like this elsewhere, even if it *weren't* too old.